# Using scanner to read text file and make a string for the words and an int array for the numbers Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, file, java.util.scanner

It compiles but doesn't do anything once I type in file name.

This is for a decoding program where there is a string in the text file (the key phrase) and a code in numbers which you have to decode by looking them up in the index of the string.

Example text file:

six perfect quality black jewels amazed the governor

35 10 10 33 9 24 3 17 41 8 3 20 51 16 38 44 47 32 33 10 19 38 35 28 49

is decoded to *"attack the bridge at dawn"* using the using the numbers as char indexes for the key phrase.

Spaces and repeated letters are also counted.

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{

sc = new Scanner( System.in );
System.out.print("File name? ");

try
{
  String fileName = sc.next().trim(); //requests file name then takes out spaces
  sc = new Scanner( new File(fileName) );  

  String key = ""; 

  while (sc.hasNext()) // looks for data  
  {
    if (sc.hasNextLine()) //if data is a string
      key = sc.nextLine(); //it is stored as key
  }

  int codeLen = 0;

  while ( sc.hasNext() )   
  {
    if ( sc.hasNextInt() )  // if the data is an integer
      codeLen++; //calculates # of integers
  }

  int[] code = new int[codeLen]; //creates array of the size of the number of intergers in file
  int num;

  while ( sc.hasNext() )   
  {
    if ( sc.hasNextInt() )  
    {
      num = sc.nextInt(); //each number found is stored

      for(int x = 0; x < codeLen; x++){ 
        code[x] = num; //adds num to the array
      }
    }
  }

  System.out.println(secretcodeM(key, code)); // prints out secret message

}

}

catch ( FileNotFoundException ex )
{ 
  System.out.println("File not found." );
  System.out.println("Run the program again." );
}
```

Less important but showing this anyway, in case.

```
public static String secretcodeM(String key, int[] code){

int codeLen = code.length;

StringBuilder secret = new StringBuilder(codeLen); 

for (int x= 0; x < codeLen; x++) //goes through code
{
  int index = code[x]; //finds the numbers in code and stores as index

  char a = key.charAt(index); //finds the character in the index in key

  secret.append(a); // add a to secret 
}

return secret.toString();
}
```

If you can tell what's wrong, can you please help out?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through program execution in your debugger? When you say your program "doesn't do anything" after you supply a filename, does it complete or keep running forever?

Comment: I haven't since I didn't learn how to do that yet.  I'll try looking that up.  It completes after I enter a filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my code:

```
    String fileName = "PathToFile";
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();

    //read file to an ArrayList
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName))) {

        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            strings.add(line);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String code = strings.get(0);
    String key = strings.get(1);

    //cast String key to int[]
    String[] numbers = key.split(" ");
    int[] keyArr = new int[numbers.length];
    for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        keyArr[i] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);
    }
```

Then you can invoke `secretcodeM(code, keyArr)`

Comment: I want to make only the numbers in the text file into an int array and save the words as a string, then send it to my method. But this is helpful too.

Comment: Ohhhh I see! It's working now, thank you so muchhh.  >_<